# LCA program giving Segmented Fault error in C++

Tags: c++, tree

Following is my LCA program which is giving a segmentation fault error but I don't understand why?

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int data;
    struct node* left, *right;
};


struct node* lca(struct node* root, int n1, int n2){

    struct node* left,*right;
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    if (root->data == n1 || root->data == n2) 
        return root;
    left = lca(root->left,n1,n2);
    right = lca(root->right,n1,n2);

    if(left && right)
        return root;
    else (left?left:right);
}

struct node* newNode(int data){

    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}


int main(void){

    struct node *root    = newNode(20);
    root->left           = newNode(8);
    root->right          = newNode(22);
    root->left->left         = newNode(4);
    root->left->right    = newNode(12);
    root->left->right->left = newNode(10);
    root->left->right->right = newNode(14);

    int n1 = 10, n2 = 14;
    struct node *t = lca(root, n1, n2);
    printf("LCA of %d and %d is %d \n", n1, n2, t->data);

    n1 = 14, n2 = 8;
    t = lca(root, n1, n2);
    printf("LCA of %d and %d is %d \n", n1, n2, t->data);

    n1 = 10, n2 = 22;
    t = lca(root, n1, n2);
    printf("LCA of %d and %d is %d \n", n1, n2, t->data);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `else (left?left:right);`?

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is occurring because of this line

```
else (left?left:right);
```

Replace this with full `else if()` and `else` statement like this.

```
else if(left)
    return left;
else
    return right;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its running...although I don't understand how this caused the failure?